# Using a pool of passwords/keys in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to run specific tasks on a group of servers, via Ansible, but each server will be authenticated via a different key or password (actually: I have a few passwords and keys and each of them should be tried when logging in).

Is there a feature in Ansible which allows to use a pool of passwords and keys to authenticate (I do not know which key/password matches which host)? The [documentation on remote connection](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html#remote-connection-information) does not mention anything like that but there may be a solution which is not obviously pointed out by the docs.